# ¿Cómo mostrar la línea donde están los errores en compilador GCC Linux?

Tags: c, ubuntu, gcc

**¡Muy buenas!**

Me acabo de instalar Lubuntu 16.04 para programar en C.

El problemilla que tengo es que a la hora de compilar con GCC desde el terminal con el comando: `cain@cain:~/Escritorio$ gcc nombre_archivo.c -o nombre_ejecutable` me aparece el error, pero no me aparece la línea donde está este error.

En mi escuela, tenemos Xubuntu y tenemos GCC instalado, ahí si que muestra correctamente la línea donde está el error.

¿Alguien puede echarme un cable?

Gracias, un saludo!

**Imágen:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué versión de gcc tienes? Te recomiendo actualizar :D

Comment: Tiene pinta de ser un problema de los colores de la terminal, y quizás la información que falta está saliendo en color negro y por eso no se ve. Prueba a usar para compilar el comando: `gcc prueba.c -o prueba|more`. En la mayoria de los comandos el uso del pipe (`|`) desactiva el coloreado.

Comment: @NaCl Sí, ya lo actualicé. Gracias igualmente por responder :)

Comment: @abulafia Gracias! Era eso. La línea me la estaba mostrando en negro y por eso no se veía jeje. Un saludo!

Por cierto, ¿cómo marco la pregunta como "resuelta"?

Comment: Si no hay respuesta, agrega la tuya y marcala :)